# How to differentiate high dense objects and others in image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I need to lighten the high dense objects and remaining should be brighter as per the expected output image.

I have tried CLAHE, equalizedHist, inRange, convertScaleAbs methods. Please suggest how to achieve this

**equalizeHist Method**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("input_image_path")
# convert image from BGR to HSV
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# Histogram equalisation on the V-channel
img_hsv[:, :, 1] = cv2.equalizeHist(img_hsv[:, :, 1])
# now convert hsv image back from HSV to RGB
imgequalized = cv2.cvtColor(img_hsv, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
```

**CLAHE Method**

```
clahe_model = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.5, tileGridSize=(10,10))

colorimage_b = clahe_model.apply(img[:,:,0])
colorimage_g = clahe_model.apply(img[:,:,1])
colorimage_r = clahe_model.apply(img[:,:,2])

colorimage_clahe = np.stack((colorimage_b,colorimage_g,colorimage_r), axis=2)
```

- Input image:
  [image: Input Image]
- Expected Output:
  [image: Expected Output]

Comment: If you need to do something based on lightness/intensity (which you seem to want, given your input image), just convert the image to the HSL or HSI color space, then transform/mask/whatever your image based on the L or I channel, and then convert back to RGB?

Comment: I would guess that the "expected output" shown is the result of a local contrast stretch. That is more or less comparing each pixel value to the average in a region around it, or to the min and max in a region around it. You need to figure out exactly how to do this comparison, and how large the region should be, to get a match with the existing result. It'll be a bit of trial and error.